# How to identify users who install and remove an app - how to use UNNEST in the new schema

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I want to identify users who install and remove an app. This has been previously answered elsewhere: [SQL Query to find users that install and uninstall an App on the same day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224663/sql-query-to-find-users-that-install-and-uninstall-an-app-on-the-same-day)

However, this uses the old schema and I am unsure of how to rework this using the new. The UNNEST function, with event_dim is the biggest problem, as there does not seem to be a clear alternative to this in the new schema.

```
#standardSQL

SELECT event_date,user_pseudo_id,event_name


FROM

`appDataFromFirebase.events_*`



WHERE event_name = "app_remove" OR event_name = "first_open"
```

This gives me all users who have either app_remove or first_open. What I actually want is those users who have both, and include the dates on which these event occurred. (edited to make clearer what I require).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` to get the users:

```
SELECT user_pseudo_id,
       MIN(CASE WHEN event_name = 'first_open' THEN event_date END) as app_remove_date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN event_name = 'app_remove' THEN event_date END) as app_remove_date
FROM `appDataFromFirebase.events_*`
WHERE event_name IN ('app_remove', 'first_open')
GROUP BY user_pseudo_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT event_name) = 2;
```

Comment: That's awesome. How could this be modified to include event_date? i.e. include the first_open and app_remove dates?

e.g. user_pseudo_id first_openDate app_removeDate as columns?

Comment: @user3156990 . . . I see you did ask for this in the question.  I've added the logic.

Comment: I was not entirely clear, my bad! Thanks for your continued help. Unfortunately it's throwing up an error: 'Expected keyword ELSE or keyword END but got ")" at [2:63]'. Any suggestions? Thanks